# Why does NelmioApiDocBundle generate the Nelmio doc, but cannot generate Swagger json?

Tags: symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I started a fresh Symfony 2.8 project that I would like to document using swagger.
I installed [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html) and it is working fine. Here is my only route:

```
/**
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *     section="Notification",
 *      resource=true,
 *   description="This method receive a notification and send it to the people concerned",
 *   parameters={
 *      {"name"="message", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="The message to be send"}
 *  })
 *
 * @Route("/notify")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function postNotifyAction(Request $request)
{ ...
```

My routing.yml:

```
notification:
    resource: "@NotificationBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
NelmioApiDocBundle:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /api/doc
nelmio_api_swagger:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/swagger_routing.yml"
    prefix: /api/swagger
```

When I access the route `/api/doc` it is working fine:

[image: Nelmio doc]

But the swagger one: `/api/swagger` (that should be working according to: [This doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/swagger-support.html)) is empty for my route:

[image]

The command app/console `api:swagger:dump` is working fine:
[image]

Am I missing something ?